# Trouble Configuring Zabbix Exporter with Prometheus for Grafana Dashboards

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, prometheus, grafana

I'm currently attempting to set up Zabbix Exporter to fetch Zabbix metrics into Prometheus for visualization in Grafana dashboards. My goal is to utilize Grafana's features for creating insightful visualizations, as I've found some limitations in displaying specific metrics, such as the free size of a datastore relative to the total size.

I successfully installed Prometheus, and it seems to be functioning as expected. However, when integrating the Zabbix Exporter from GitHub, despite configuring it correctly and creating a systemd unit file, the Prometheus server returns the following error:

```
server returned HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error
```

As far as I can tell, the Zabbix Exporter is up and running smoothly, indicated by an "active" status in its systemd service. Nevertheless, the issue persists in Prometheus. I've checked the configured port, ensuring it matches the default, and I couldn't find any errors in either the Zabbix or Prometheus logs via journalctl.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I myself cant access that link.

Comment: Prometheus has a web interface running on port 9090, that's the first thing you should check. Likewise, the Zabbix Exporter should be running on its own port too, presumably 9224. You should be able to check that as well with your browser. I am not sure where you saw that HTTP/500 error.